# Does Wordpress provide themes_api function?

Tags: themes, updates, api, wordpress.org

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/communicating-with-the-wordpress-org-plugin-api/

From the link above, we can see the Wordpress.org provide a function that can access the Wordpress.org plugins and get the plugins information from there...

But I search on google for few days already...still cannot found any information about the wordpress.org themes api. Is Wordpress provide a function like plugins_api? And the usage of the themes_api(if available)? That is my question.

Comment: The answer is yes otherwise you would not have been able to see the details of theme on your wordpress. Asking for the description of the usage is not really a question, but it should be relatively easy to learn from the wordpress source code.

Comment: According to wpseek.com, there is a [`themes_api()`](http://wpseek.com/themes_api/) function in WordPress. There isn't currently an entry in the Codex for it, though. As @MarkKaplun points out, you can examine WP's source code to work out what it does: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/theme.php In the current version, the `themes_api()` function starts at line 274.